# Segmentation fault at run time in c++ class

Tags: c++, stl

hi I see this error when running the below code. "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" I cant fine the reason.\ someone help me. thanks

```
#ifndef __LIB_TAG_STRINGS_H__
#define __LIB_TAG_STRINGS_H__

//============
//stl
#include <deps.h>
#include <string>
namespace tags
 {
   const std::string tag1 ("TAG_1");
   const std::string tag2 ("TAG_2");
 }//END namespace TAGS

namespace attributes
 {
  const std::string attribute1 ("ATTRIBUTE_1");
  const std::string attribute2("ATTRIBUTE_2");
 }

class _Name 
 {
  public:

  _Name ()
   {
    /**This constructor is used to map some tags with the strings**/
    string_map.insert (std::make_pair (std::string ("TAGNOTE1"), tags::tag1 ));
    string_map.insert (std::make_pair (std::string ("TAGNOTE2"), tags::tag2 ));
   };

 const std::string& getName (const std::string& class_name) const
   {   
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator i = string_map.find(class_name);
    return (i != string_map.end ()) ? i->second : null_string;
  }


   private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> string_map;
    std::string null_string;
 };

namespace Name
 {
  const _Name NAME;
 }
#endif
```

core was dump at run time. this is the code in which GDB is pointing an error.

GDB Logs:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003b00e9d23b in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.5.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
(gdb) where
0  0x000strong text0003b00e9d23b in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
1  0x00007ffff1375372 in _Name::_Name (this=0x7ffff15a9b60)
    at /prog/lib/tag_strings.h:229
2  0x00007ffff139581b in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 ()
    at /prog/lib/tag_strings.h:257
3  global constructors keyed to dest.cxx(void) () at dest.cxx:679
4  0x00007ffff1398516 in __do_global_ctors_aux () from ./dest.so
5  0x00007ffff135a2bb in _init () from ./dest.so
6  0x00007fffe361f000 in ?? ()
7  0x0000003af860e535 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
8  0x0000003af8600b3a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
9  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
10 0x00007fffffffe128 in ?? ().
11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ().
```

Comment: hi I see this error when running the below code. "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" I cant fine the reason.\ someone help me. thanks

Comment: Where is `main()`? And what is `<deps.h>`?

Comment: Okay, GDB tells you where the crash is. Would you mind telling _us_ where the crash is?

Comment: @AndyProwl deps.h contains the list of included header files

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please find the0 0x000strong text0003b00e9d23b in std::basic_string, std::allocator>::basic_string(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

       #1 0x00007ffff1375372 in _Name::_Name (this=0x7ffff15a9b60) at /prog/lib/tag_strings.h:229

      #2 0x00007ffff139581b in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 () at /prog/lib/tag_strings.h:257

Comment: Except that you have global identifiers with a leading underscore (those are reserved by the specification) there is nothing really wrong with your code. At least not what you show.

Comment: Actually the crash in std::basic_string is perfectly consistent with the explanation in my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a static intitialization order problem.

When your NAME object is constructed, it accesses the tag1/tag2 objects - but there is no guarantee that these were constructed yet!

You could try changing the objects that are depended upon to functions.

```
namespace tags {
    static std::string tag1() { return std::string("TAG1"); }
    ...
}

...
string_map.insert (std::make_pair (std::string ("TAGNOTE1"), tags::tag1() ));
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot @hmn code is working now. I want to ask that why the previous code was working fine with solaris.

Comment: The order in which tag1, tag2 and NAME are initialized is undefined - you can think of it as random. Sometimes it is already enough to re-compile the code in order for such a crash to (temporarily) disappear.